# Lazy initialization using self and unown self,

Tags: swift, initialization, closures

I was just experimenting with properties using lazy initialization in a class, here is my code:

```
class Person {

    let firstName: String

    lazy var greeting: String = {

        return "Hello, my name is \(self.firstName)"        
    }()

    init(firstName: String){
        self.firstName = firstName
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}


var Brendon: Person? = Person(firstName: "Brendon")
var greeting = Brendon!.greeting

Brendon = nil  //*deinitialized*
```

I was trying to find out if I didn't put `[unowned self] in` in the closure, would the class de-initialize, what I expect is it won't run the `deinit{}` method because there would be a retain cycle, but it turns out that it does in fact de-initialize. Shouldn't there be a retain cycle?

**UPDATE**

What my brain is telling me is: since the closure is referencing self and the class has a reference to the closure (because it is inside the body of the class), therefore if I didn't put `[unowned self]`, as I set `Brendon = nil`, the closure is keeping the `Brendon` instance alive. Thus, a retain cycle, am I correct?

Comment: There should be a retain cycle because the closure is referencing self and the class has a reference to the closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
lazy var greeting: String = {
    return "Hello, my name is \(self.firstName)"        
}()
```

... there is no retained closure. Notice the `()`. This is just a function, like any other; it is *called*, not stored. `greeting` is a String, not a stored closure.

Comment: If retain cycles worked the way you seem to imagine, every function in the world would have to have `unowned self`!

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks bud, in this article, look for the `Person class` http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/ , why did he use `[unowned self] in` in that case?

Comment: Wow, I just realised you are Matt Neuburg, I literally purchased your book two days ago...